# How can I suppress a forced restart caused by my bootstrapper?

Tags: .net, wix, installation, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I have a `setup.exe` bootstrapper that gets generated for my installer:

```
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="Blah" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="False" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\BootStrapper" ApplicationRequiresElevation="True" Culture="en-US" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'"/>
```

Part of its conditional installation step is to download and install the Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for office Runtime 4.0 redistributable, but **this redistributable will always force a restart** on my machine (Windows 8.1 Pro, x64):

```
<BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.VSTORuntime.4.0">
  <ProductName>Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
```

Is there any way to not allow this redistributable to force a restart on the system, like forcing the installation to run with lower privileges, or doing anything that can possibly, at all, stop it from restarting the system forcefully?

Answer (score 2):

If you run vstor_redist.exe with a /? command line, the one I ran showed a message box with options. One of them is /norestart

The potential issue is that without a reboot at some point the installation may not be complete, so it may not be fully functional until after a reboot.

Edit: I think the bootstrapper lets you specify the command line in the exepackage node, as in this example I found:

ExePackage Id="Net45" Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Setup" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" InstallCommand="/q"

Comment: I have no clue how you can pass command line arguments down to the bootstrapper's downloaded MSI's though!

Comment: @Alexandru Instead of the VS 2005 bootstrapper, consider the WiX Bootstrapper (sometimes called "burn," after the name of its engine).  It's also a bundler, downloader, chainer, reboot manager, and package manager. (For some, being a package manager is undesirable.) Burn is used by the Visual Studio installer (and the WiX installer, of course).

Comment: @TomBlodget That's exactly the path I went down, in the end!